# Declaring static const variables in functions

Tags: c#

If declaring static variables inside functions is an error then why declaring implicitly static const variables in functions not an error in c#

```cs
class Hello{
   public void hello(){
       static int h;  //error
   }
}

class Hello{
   public void hello(){
       const int h=33;   //const implicitly static
   }
}
```

Comment: There's a lengthy discussion of why C# doesn't support static variables inside functions [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/05/11/why-doesnt-c-support-static-method-variables/).

Comment: `static` variables in functions are not allowed. `const` variables are. `const` variables are not "implicitly static" except in your imagination, because `static` variables in functions are not allowed. You're looking at this through C-colored glasses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean something like

```
void Main()
{
  const int c = 1;

  Console.WriteLine (c == 1);
}
```

Which is legal because *it limits the scope of `c` to that function*.  All the compiler does with the constant local is replace all instances of that reference with the constant value.  So if you decompile the code you'll see:

```
void Main()
{
  Console.WriteLine (1 == 1);
}
```

There is no such thing as static *locals* in C#.  Static locals in C++ are local variables that retain their values across calls to that method.  In C# you'd use a static *member* instead.  Constant *class members* are *implicitly* `static` because there's no reason to make them *instance* properties.  But that doesn't mean that `const` *varaibles* are "static" in the same sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `static variables` inside your `main method` (or any other method), but you need to declare them in the `class`:

This is totally fine:

```
public Class YourClass 
{
  static int anyNumber = 5;

  static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    Console.WriteLine(anyNumber);
  }
}
```

This is fine too, but in this case, `anyNumber` is a local variable, not a static one.

```
public Class YourClass 
{

  static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    int anyNumber = 5;
    Console.WriteLine(anyNumber);
  }
}
```